# Speed up Cell replacement VBA

Tags: excel, vba, replace, cell

I have a little code that formats phone numbers in a column, in the sense that:
-if it has spaces in between, it removes them
-after that, takes 9 numbers starting from the right, and checks if it is a integer, and if so, puts that in the cell.

The problem is that it takes nearly 6-7 seconds to do all the replacements (3000 cells, most of them blank). Any idea how to speed up this, pls?

Many thanks

````
targetSheet.Columns("M:M").Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
  

For i = 2 To targetSheet.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Len(targetSheet.Cells(i, 13).Value) > 9 Then
        Phone = Right(targetSheet.Cells(i, 13).Value, 9)
        If IsNumeric(Phone) = True Then
            targetSheet.Cells(i, 13).Value = Phone
        Else
            targetSheet.Cells(i, 13).Value = ""
        End If
    End If
Next i```
````

Comment: Which part? The replace? or the for loop? It looks like your for loop is skipping cells with a length of less than nine, that should be skipping the blanks.

NOTE: You can remove `= True` from anywhere you see it. It's a double evaluation. The pattern is `If Boolean Then`.

Comment: Each worksheet write is going to prompt a recalc of dependent cells, and while cells are being written to, Excel attempts to slip in between two VBA instructions to repaint the worksheet - you can "speed up" the execution of your code by switching off recalcs and repaints before you loop, and switching them back on afterwards. See `Application.Calculation` and `Application.ScreenUpdating`. If you have `Worksheet_Change` event handlers running, disable events too (see `Application.EnableEvents`).

Comment: Very good points there, many thanks!

Comment: FYI you might find it frustrating to have entries which are *almost* phone numbers deleted because they were not "perfect", without a chance to correct them, so it might better to highlight the problem entries than to delete them?

Comment: Hi Tim, you're totally right. Many thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cell Replacement by Using an Array

- You could 'apply' the removing of the spaces to the range. For the remaining job, write the range values to an array, modify them and write them back to the range.

**EDIT:**

- Note that I have added three missing `Replace` arguments since `False` is not their default value: `MatchCase` for sure, the last two unclear. `SearchOrder` and `MatchByte` are not important in this case. Read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim trg As Range
    With targetSheet.Range("M2")
        Set trg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If trg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set trg = .Resize(trg.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    trg.Replace What:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False 
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = trg.Value
    Dim cValue As Variant
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        cValue = Data(i, 1)
        If Not IsError(cValue) Then
            If Len(cValue) > 9 Then
                cValue = Right(cValue, 9)
                If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
                    Data(i, 1) = cValue
                Else
                    Data(i, 1) = ""
                End If
            'Else ' Len(cValue) is lte 9
            End If
        'Else ' error value
        End If
    Next i
    trg.Value = Data
End Sub
```

Comment: Wowmany thanks!! That goes really fast, nice and clean!